# NodeJS - azure-storage-node- , how to retrieve addition of two columns, and apply filtering condition

Tags: node.js, azure

Sorry for being newbie for NodeJs and table query, my question's,
How I could create a query using Nodejs pakcage "azure-storage-node", which selects the sum/addition of two coloumns 'start' and 'period' , if the addition is greater than a threshold it will take the whole raw, my tries which didn't work is something like this,

```
var query = new azure.TableQuery();
total = query.select(['start']) + query.select(['period']);
query.where('total > ?' , 50000);
```

or may be something like this,

```
var query = new azure.TableQuery()
.where('start + period gt 50000');
```

but it throws an error of '+'.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to accomplish is not possible with Azure Tables at least as of today as Azure Tables has limited querying support and support for computed columns (if I may say so) is not there.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Have an attribute called `total` in your entities that will contain the value i.e. `start + period`. You calculate this value when you're inserting or updating the entity and store it at that time.
2. Do this filtering on the client side. For this you will need to download all related entities and then apply this filtering on the client side on the data that you fetched.